# How does service account authentication work with the Ruby Google API?

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client

I see the service account source code in the API, but I can't figure out how this would be used to authenticate with a Google service. All the examples I've seen are for other authentication scenarios, not *service account*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got added a few days ago and docs haven't been updated yet. Just created a page on the wiki that hopefully gets you started.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/ServiceAccounts

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that out. I'm wondering: when authenticating this way, can the app access public calendars?